# Arduino C++ related problems

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-c++, dot-matrix

I am trying to make a digital watch using DS3231 RTC module and arduino UNO so while uploading the sketch the display of LED MAX17219 glitches and shows random pixels with text that i want to keep.

Here the code and may I know if there is any problem
or if there not is it related to hardware problems. I will tell hardware model if u insist

[image: Error]

I tried to look up solution everywhere but couldn't find the problem of
is it hardware one or code one
I can send photo of wire connection and others if needed

```
// Use the Parola library to scroll text on the display
//
// Demonstrates the use of the scrolling function to display text received
// from the serial interface
//
// User can enter text on the serial monitor and this will display as a
// scrolling message on the display.
// Speed for the display is controlled by a pot on SPEED_IN analog in.
// Scrolling direction is controlled by a switch on DIRECTION_SET digital in.
// Invert ON/OFF is set by a switch on INVERT_SET digital in.
//
// UISwitch library can be found at https://github.com/MajicDesigns/MD_UISwitch
// MD_MAX72XX library can be found at https://github.com/MajicDesigns/MD_MAX72XX
//

#include <MD_Parola.h>
#include <MD_MAX72xx.h>
#include <SPI.h>

// set to 1 if we are implementing the user interface pot, switch, etc
#define USE_UI_CONTROL 0

#if USE_UI_CONTROL
#include <MD_UISwitch.h>
#endif

// Turn on debug statements to the serial output
#define DEBUG 0

#if DEBUG
#define PRINT(s, x) { Serial.print(F(s)); Serial.print(x); }
#define PRINTS(x) Serial.print(F(x))
#define PRINTX(x) Serial.println(x, HEX)
#else
#define PRINT(s, x)
#define PRINTS(x)
#define PRINTX(x)
#endif

// Define the number of devices we have in the chain and the hardware interface
// NOTE: These pin numbers will probably not work with your hardware and may
// need to be adapted
#define HARDWARE_TYPE MD_MAX72XX::FC16_HW
#define MAX_DEVICES 11
#define CLK_PIN   13
#define DATA_PIN  11
#define CS_PIN    10

// HARDWARE SPI
MD_Parola P = MD_Parola(HARDWARE_TYPE, CS_PIN, MAX_DEVICES);
// SOFTWARE SPI
//MD_Parola P = MD_Parola(HARDWARE_TYPE, DATA_PIN, CLK_PIN, CS_PIN, MAX_DEVICES);

// Scrolling parameters
#if USE_UI_CONTROL
const uint8_t SPEED_IN = A5;
const uint8_t DIRECTION_SET = 8;  // change the effect
const uint8_t INVERT_SET = 9;     // change the invert

const uint8_t SPEED_DEADBAND = 5;
#endif // USE_UI_CONTROL

uint8_t scrollSpeed = 25;    // default frame delay value
textEffect_t scrollEffect = PA_SCROLL_LEFT;
textPosition_t scrollAlign = PA_LEFT;
uint16_t scrollPause = 2000; // in milliseconds

// Global message buffers shared by Serial and Scrolling functions
#define BUF_SIZE    75
char curMessage[BUF_SIZE] = { "" };
char newMessage[BUF_SIZE] = { "Hello! Enter new message?" };
bool newMessageAvailable = true;

#if USE_UI_CONTROL

MD_UISwitch_Digital uiDirection(DIRECTION_SET);
MD_UISwitch_Digital uiInvert(INVERT_SET);

void doUI(void)
{
  // set the speed if it has changed
  {
    int16_t speed = map(analogRead(SPEED_IN), 0, 1023, 10, 150);

    if ((speed >= ((int16_t)P.getSpeed() + SPEED_DEADBAND)) ||
      (speed <= ((int16_t)P.getSpeed() - SPEED_DEADBAND)))
    {
      P.setSpeed(speed);
      scrollSpeed = speed;
      PRINT("\nChanged speed to ", P.getSpeed());
    }
  }

  if (uiDirection.read() == MD_UISwitch::KEY_PRESS) // SCROLL DIRECTION
  {
    PRINTS("\nChanging scroll direction");
    scrollEffect = (scrollEffect == PA_SCROLL_LEFT ? PA_SCROLL_RIGHT : PA_SCROLL_LEFT);
    P.setTextEffect(scrollEffect, scrollEffect);
    P.displayClear();
    P.displayReset();
  }

  if (uiInvert.read() == MD_UISwitch::KEY_PRESS)  // INVERT MODE
  {
    PRINTS("\nChanging invert mode");
    P.setInvert(!P.getInvert());
  }
}
#endif // USE_UI_CONTROL

void readSerial(void)
{
  static char *cp = newMessage;

  while (Serial.available())
  {
    *cp = (char)Serial.read();
    if ((*cp == '\n') || (cp - newMessage >= BUF_SIZE-2)) // end of message character or full buffer
    {
      *cp = '\0'; // end the string
      // restart the index for next filling spree and flag we have a message waiting
      cp = newMessage;
      newMessageAvailable = true;
    }
    else  // move char pointer to next position
      cp++;
  }
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(57600);
  Serial.print("\n[Parola Scrolling Display]\nType a message for the scrolling display\nEnd message line with a newline");

#if USE_UI_CONTROL
  uiDirection.begin();
  uiInvert.begin();
  pinMode(SPEED_IN, INPUT);

  doUI();
#endif // USE_UI_CONTROL

  P.begin();
  P.displayText(curMessage, scrollAlign, scrollSpeed, scrollPause, scrollEffect, scrollEffect);
}

void loop()
{
#if USE_UI_CONTROL
  doUI();
#endif // USE_UI_CONTROL

  if (P.displayAnimate())
  {
    if (newMessageAvailable)
    {
      strcpy(curMessage, newMessage);
      newMessageAvailable = false;
    }
    P.displayReset();
  }
  readSerial();
}
```

Comment: Based on the output, your code seems to be compiling OK but is having issues being written to COM3. Is this the correct port that your Arduino is connected to?

Comment: yes, i have connected it